# Mysql: Searching for data by month only yields one result not all of them

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an Orders table with the Date_ordered column.

I am trying to select the average price of all of the items ordered that were purchased in the month of December.

I used

```
select *, avg(price) from orders where monthname(date_ordered) = "december"
```

However it is only coming up with one result, when my table has 4 instances of the date being xxxx-12-xx

Note: There are multiple years included in the data but they are irrelevant to the query I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put `avg()` into the `select`, you turn the query into an aggregation query.  Without a `group by`, SQL *always* returns on row.  If you want the average as well as the other data, then use a `join` or subselect:

```
select o.*, oo.avgp
from orders o cross join
     (select avg(price) as avgp from orders where month(date_ordered) = 12) oo
where month(o.date_ordered) = 12;
```

Answer (score 1):

`avg()` in your query is a group function. If there is no `GROUP BY` clause in your query, it causes the group function to be applied on all selected rows. So you are getting average of the four prices in that field. And the average is only one.

Answer (score 0):

AVG() is an aggregate function.  It averages every value in the price column and condenses the result into a single row.  You could [group](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) your result by another column, or consider if you really want to use avg()